# Remove File name from URL & keep 2 GET variables in the URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am developing a website where I need to create a specific URL structure... So How to make this url:

```
http://example.com/index.php?city=mumbai&place=chembur
```

into this:

```
http://example.com/mumbai/chembur
```

Is it possible?

Edit:

I have tried using following code in htaccess file but it displays an empty page

```
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?city=$1&place=$2 [L,QSA]

# RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Edit: I am selecting @AbsoluteBeginner answer because its less code & 0 errors. I know it is not url redirecting but it is solving my problem.

Also, thank you @CallofDev for so much help!

Comment: @Evert I have edited my question

Comment: @anubhava yes I tested .htaccess is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple PHP Router.

.htaccess

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

index.php

```
$path = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$city = $path[1]; // mumbai
$place = $path[2]; // chembur

// Do what you want with those two variables (database query or include a file).
```

This will give you full control over the url structure. It's not an url rewriting, it's a different approach.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand how this will convert this URL http://example.com/index.php?city=mumbai&place=chembur into this : http://example.com/mumbai/chembur

Comment: Now the URL is like this example.com/?mumbai/chembur  However I want to remove the ? from the url as well

Comment: You don't need to add ? after example.com, because no variable is passed through the URL. This wil be: example.com/mumbai/chembur (exactly what you want).

Answer (score 2):

Here we have to treat the rules separately so as to obtain specific url incase you have only one variable or both of them.In your case what you did was assigned conditions to the same rule hence didn't work. So we define Conditions for both URL formats. The first rule wil work if only the value of city is passed and the other will work only if both values are passed. Here this link will help you know how the rules are checked https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=1fe76858-2b15-5848-bbbe-32e55b692e1e.

```
RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?city=$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?city=$1&place=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. I tried this but its giving me object not found error.. (I am working on xampp)

Comment: Did you try changing AllowOverride to All in httpd.conf file.

Comment: I tried that but no use.. Also, have tried testing it on a shared hosting but it gives internal server error

Comment: Thanks man you saved my day =D I uploaded script in the subfolder but then moved to root and it worked!

Comment: Its our pleasure to be able to help you out. cheers!

Comment: If one parameter is not passed in the url then it gives the server error, this Url will give the error http://example.com/mumbai/  If one parameter is not speciefied then that url should still load

Comment: Ok, so to be clear you want to be able to pass that variable to the page even if the second variable is not specified.

Comment: yes I want to be able to pass that variable to the page even if the second variable is not specified.

Comment: I tried that now only one variable is passed and second variable is not revived via GET. Also if you  could elaborate your code a bit that will be very helpful for me and others as well

Comment: I re-edited the code. Hope it solves your problem this time.